# open関数を使うとエラー (unicode error) が出てしまいます

Tags: python

pythonでボタンを押すと指定したファイルを開く簡単なランチャーを作ろうとしたのですが、

```
f = open("C:\Users\hoge\Documents\python programs", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

の部分で

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。どうすれば解決できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

文字列リテラル中の`\`はエスケープに使われます。  
例えば `\n` が改行、`\t` がタブ、`\\` が `\` 自身などです。  
ですので `"C:\Users ……` という文字列の `\U` 以下がエスケープシーケンスと見なされています。  
`\Uxxxxxxxx` は文字コードを指定するエスケープシーケンスです。(http://docs.python.jp/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?#string-and-bytes-literals)

解決方法は、

1. raw文字を使えばエスケープは解釈され無いので r を付けて、`r"C:\Users ……` と書く。
2. `\`自身を表すため `\\` とし `"C:\\Users ……` と書く。
3. Unix系のようにディレクトリの区切りに `/` を使う。(Windows であっても、Python がよろしくやってくれると思います)

あたりでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

"\Uxxxx"はエスケープシーケンスとして処理されます。
プレフィックスに'r'を付ける事で解決します。

```
r"C:\Users\hoge\Documents\python programs"
```

'r'を使うことで、raw文字列として扱われ、"\U"がエスケープシーケンスとして処理されなくなります。

参考サイト
http://docs.python.jp/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals
https://hydrocul.github.io/wiki/programming_languages_diff/string/escape.html
http://www.pythonweb.jp/tutorial/string/index4.html